# Multilanguage select on dropdown, typing enable in textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, multilingual

I am working on a flex project. I want to implement a title window in which I have a dropdown with multi language options, selected one option e.g no_NO for Norwegian language. Now user should able to write in Norwegian language in a text area in that window.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Flex provides a mechanism using resource bundles and the ResourceManager. There should be some examples in the official documentation to support runtime localization. I implemented a smal example a while back which shows how to avoid using resources in the markup: [localization example @ github](https://github.com/floriansalihovic/L18nExample/)